# Listen for multiple promises to complete

Tags: javascript, jquery

This works fine the the first call, but regardless on if I "reset" the deferred objects, `$.when` will only trigger once, unless I rebind it inside the click handler.

Is there any way to make a global listener for several promises, that can be resetted?

I've thought about custom events and a pub/sub pattern as well. They work great for single events, but I can't figure out a good way to use them for my scenario below.

```
var dfd1 = $.Deferred(), dfd2 = $.Deferred();

$('input').on('click', function(){
    dfd1 = $.Deferred();
    dfd2 = $.Deferred();
    f1();
    f2();
});

$.when.apply($, [dfd1, dfd2]).then(function(schemas) {
    console.log('done');
});

function f1(){
    setTimeout(dfd1.resolve, 500);
}

function f2(){
    setTimeout(dfd2.resolve, 600);
}

f1();
f2();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/C62gh/

Comment: No. Promises simply are not made to be "resettable".

Comment: Psst! Switching to [real promises](http://promises-aplus.github.io/promises-spec/) anytime soon? :-) https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/Coming-from-jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: You have to call `$.when` again every time you create new deferreds.

The problem with your code is that you don't "reset" the deferred objects (and in fact they *cannot* be reset) -- you are replacing some references to these objects with references to other (unresolved) deferreds.

Note that I said *some* references because the references you are replacing are not unique: the array that you passed to `$.when` holds separate references to the same deferreds, and those references have of course not been replaced. Even if they had, `$.when` has no way to know about that even if it wanted to.

Comment: Ok, can you think of a more suitable pattern? I'm not very satisfied with the current solution.

Comment: @Johan: The only thing you can do is wrap the required machinery into a function so that the intent takes center stage instead of the mechanism. There is nothing else.

Comment: You should have a look at functional reactive programming libraries.

Comment: @Bergi: I 'm only familiar with [Rx](https://rx.codeplex.com/) to be frank -- any tips on what to look at in JS?

Comment: Imho the only reasonable (big community, good support etc) choice is Bacon.js; although if you're familiar with Rx there [is a port of it to JS](http://rxjs.codeplex.com/) as well